# ViewWillAppear or NumberOfCellsInSection? which will happen first?

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery, viewwillappear

I'm working on this app that uses [parse.com](http://parse.com), and I have to make a Query and make the objects into arrays. I made that into a method and put it in `viewWillAppear` method, but I still see nothing!

I don't know where else to put it, nor how can I make it call the method `getObjects()` whenever the `viewWillAppear` is called, and then apply it to the tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check that out by putting a println("we are in xxx") in those methods to checkout which one loads the first.

But do you reload your tableView data :
    self.tableView.reloadData()
after you loaded your parse data ?

Comment: let me try that i knew there was some reload method but i didn't know what it was

Comment: ive used the print statement to prove that it is getting the objects and addeing them to the array but its not showing it in the tableveiws

Comment: no dude you were right i just had to find the right spot to put the reload data thanks so much man

Comment: Use a PFQueryTableViewController which has automatic support for querying, pull-to-refresh, loading screen, pagination, automatic management of PFObjects, etc

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common scenario and will be a breeze to accomplish with the right tools. You can build out your own functionality for Parse within a TableViewController or you can use Parse's own PFQueryTableViewController to accomplish exactly what you want very easily.

[Check out a tutorial to help get you started](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581)

[Here's another just in case](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/)

The gist of it is, you must query Parse for data to fill the TableViewController's data source and then reload the table's data once it is fetched. With PFQueryTableViewController, all you have to do is specify a query in the function queryForTable(). PFQueryTableViewController is included in the ParseUI framework (along with a bunch of other great tools) which you will want to import.